# File extension changes when I try to rename Pytube video while downloading

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to rename my downloaded Pytube video but when I try to change the filename, the file extension changes from mp4 to file.

Here's my code:

```
yt = YouTube("https://youtu.be/Igo8pUqvFMc")
stream_type = int(input("Types: \n1. Video only \n2. Audio only \n3. Video awith audio \nEnter the number of the type you want to download: "))

if stream_type == 1:
    videos = yt.streams.filter(only_video=True, adaptive=True, file_extension="mp4")
    vid = list(enumerate(videos))
    for i in vid:
        print(i)
    stream_no = int(input("Enter: "))
    videos[stream_no].download(filename=yt.title + " VIDEO ONLY")
```

Comment: You are explicitly passing a filename to `.download()` that doesn't have an extension, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `download()` passes in a filename with no file extension. This is the file name used to save the file. Instead, add the `mp4` extension at the end:

```py
yt = YouTube("https://youtu.be/Igo8pUqvFMc")
stream_type = int(input("Types: \n1. Video only \n2. Audio only \n3. Video awith audio \nEnter the number of the type you want to download: "))

if stream_type == 1:
    videos = yt.streams.filter(only_video=True, adaptive=True, file_extension="mp4")
    vid = list(enumerate(videos))
    for i in vid:
        print(i)
    stream_no = int(input("Enter: "))
    videos[stream_no].download(filename=yt.title + " VIDEO ONLY.mp4")
```

Comment: Oh it was this simple!! Thank you so much. However, when I download it. the file can't be opened because it says "could not decode the format "av01" (AOMedia's AV1 Video)" even the though the file says it's in MP4 format. I've tried all the built-in media players in windows. Any solution for this?

Comment: @bliss You just aren't using a media player that supports this format. Either update them (if that's possible) or use a different media player like [MPC-HC](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc).